# Expected value of average of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus

For a standard one-dimensional Brownian motion $W(t)$, calculate:

$$E\bigg[\Big(\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_0^TW_t\, dt\Big)^2\bigg]$$

Note: I am not able to figure out how to approach this problem. All i can think of is that the term $\frac{1}{T}\int\limits_0^TW_t\,dt$ is like 'average'. But not sure how to proceed ahead. I'm relatively new to Brownian motion. I tried searching the forum for some hints..but could not find one. I will really appreciate if you could please guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you recall that $\mathrm d(t W_t) = W_t\mathrm dt + t\mathrm dW_t$ you can write your integral in the other form
$$
  \int_0^T W_t\mathrm dt = TW_T - \int_0^Tt\mathrm dW_t.
$$
If we forget about the factor $\frac1T$ as it does not affect the derivation much, we obtain
$$
  \mathsf E\left(\int_0^T W_t\mathrm dt\right)^2 = \mathsf E\left[T^2W_T^2\right] - 2T\mathsf E\left[W_T\int_0^T t\mathrm dW_t\right]+\mathsf E\left(\int_0^T t\mathrm dW_t\right)^2
$$
$$
  = T^3- 2T\int_0^Tt\mathrm dt+\int_0^Tt^2\mathrm dt
$$
where we applied the [Ito isometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_isometry) a couple of times. Hopefully, the most hard part now is done an you can finish the derivations.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!. Got the answer as T/3.

Comment: @PrakharMehrotra: you are welcome

Comment: @S.D. what is the expectation with regards to here?

Answer (score 6):

Another approach would be to show that the random variable

$$\omega \mapsto \int_0^T W_t(\omega) \, dt$$

is a centered normal random variable with variance $\int_0^T (s-T)^2 \, ds=\frac{T^3}{3}$. You can find a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/integral-of-brownian-motion-is-gaussian/243977#243977). (The proof is a bit lenghthy, but you don't need Itô-Calculus to prove it.)

Comment: The variance is not T.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 5):

Expand the square as
$$
\left(\int_0^TW_t\, \mathrm dt\right)^2=\int_0^T\int_0^t2W_tW_s\,\mathrm ds\mathrm dt,
$$
and use Fubini theorem and the identity $\mathbb E(W_tW_s)=s$ for every $s\leqslant t$ to conclude that the expectation you want to compute is
$$
\frac1{T^2}\int_0^T\int_0^t2s\,\mathrm ds\mathrm dt=\frac{T}3.
$$

Comment: thanks for your reply. I read about [Fubini theorem] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) and also follow your explanation about $E(W_tW_s)$. Could you please elaborate on expanding the square of the integral?

Comment: No: this is straightforward and if you think one second about it you will see this is true in full generality.

Comment: @PrakharMehrotra this comment might come a tad late, but you might be confused about the expansion of the square integral provided by Did because it is wrong, there is an extra '2'.

Comment: @Iliana Better now? (Yes your comment comes late. It is not most polite either.)

Comment: @Did oops sorry if I didn't sound very polite, I would rephrase my answer but stackexchange won't let me. Better late than ever I suppose...