# find the probability and standard deviation of gambling

Tags: probability

let us suppose we have following  task : the husband  is playing the internet game, in which he is winning or losing    1 dollar  with equal probability, we should find  a) mean value of this game and standard deviation

its seems that this game  is  a brownian motion, because at initial state husband   has zero value

$W(0)=0$

and at probability of $p=0.5$ , he sometimes go up, sometimes go down, i found following link about brownian  motion

[brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250526/expected-value-of-average-of-brownian-motion)

but i could not find  its connection to this problem, actualy mean value should be equal to $0$, because we have  $x_1=1$ and  $x_2=-1$, and  expected value is equal to

$1*0.1+(-1)*0.5=0$

about standard  deviation   we would have

$1^2*0.5+(-1)^2*0.5-0^2=1$

from this we have  $\sqrt{1} $

am i right?please help me , i am thinking about  some distribution (binomial for instance) , we number of trials is equal to infinity, therefore

Comment: You might look at "random walks".

Comment: mean is correct, what about  standard deviation ?

Comment: i found https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/classes/cs70_fall09/n15.pdf

Comment: Actually the variance comes out to $1$ (like you wrote before), not $2.$ The formula on the left of the $=$ is correct, it's just a matter of adding things up. (Notice that $0^2 = 0$; actually I don't see any reason to mention $0^2$ at all, since the terms $1^2 \times 1/2$ and $(-1)^2 \times 1/2$ cover all the possible outcomes of each game.)

Comment: ouuu  what  a crazy mistake :D :D  of course 0.5+0.5=1  dont pay attention

Comment: So I think you have the correct numbers now for the single game. If the husband keeps playing then the number of games grows without bound. If you can add to the question what it is you want to know about that series of games, maybe someone has an idea or a reference to suggest.