# Tricky a.e. limit question, studying the $ \text{a.e.-lim}_{t \rightarrow \infty} \frac {1}{t} \int_0 ^ t W_s ~ds$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Could someone give some advice in order to study  $$\underset{t\to\infty}{\operatorname{a.e.-lim}} \frac {1}{t} \int_0 ^ t W_s ~ds,$$ where $(W_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is a standard brownian motion starting at zero ?

Thank's in advance.

Comment: What's the definition of $W_s$.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: $W_s$ si a brownian motion as writen

Comment: what do you mean by ps-lim?

Comment: @Tim: Sorry! I was thinking in french so ps (presque sure) means a.e. (almost ever). Edited

Comment: OK, but would think that the sequence diverges for almost every path.  If it converges it must be to $0$ by symmetry. It might converge in probability to some random variable.

Comment: For fixed $t$, the integral is normally distributed with mean zero and variance of order $t^3$, so $\frac{1}{t}$ times the integral is normal with variance of order $t$.  I don't think this limit exists.

Comment: What about using double-logarithm grow arguments, or passing through the Brownian motion with an argument $\frac1t$?

Comment: @Ilya: I've tried to use an mean value argument as yours also with $1/t$ but it doesn't work. I wonder the limit does not exist.

Comment: As @ChrisJanjigian indicated (did you read this comment?), the distributions diverge hence the random variables cannot converge almost surely (and a little more work show that they diverge almost surely).

Comment: @Paul: I meant using these arguments to show divergence

Answer (score 7):

I'll turn my comment above into an answer.  Call $X_t = \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t W_s ds$.  We claim that the family $\{ X_t\}$ is not tight and therefore cannot converge in distribution (and hence cannot converge almost surely).  This is easy to see, since [$X_t$ is Gaussian with mean zero and variance of order $t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/integral-of-brownian-motion-is-gaussian).  Therefore, for any compact set $K$ $P ( X_t \in K) \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.

As Did suggested, a little more work gets a stronger result.  Clearly, for any $M$ the event $A = \{\limsup_{t \to \infty} X(t) > M \}$ is a tail event in the sigma algebra of the Brownian motion $W_s$.  Therefore $P(A) \in \{0,1 \}$.  An explicit computation using the normality above gives that $P(X(t) > M) \to \frac{1}{2}$ as $t \to \infty$ and (the reverse) Fatou's lemma then gives that $P(A) \geq \frac{1}{2}$, so $P(A) = 1$.  Therefore $P(\{\limsup_{t \to \infty} X(t) = \infty \}) = 1$.  Symmetry gives that $P(\{\liminf_{t \to \infty} X(t) = - \infty \}) = 1$.  As a result, the limit almost surely does not exist.