# Expected Value of the exponential of a stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

What is the expected value of the following process:
$$
e^{\int_0^t B_u\, du}
$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/integral-of-brownian-motion-is-gaussian) for the fact that $\int_0^t B_u du$ follows the normal distribution with zero mean and variance $\dfrac{t^3}{3}$.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) for moment generating function(MGF) of normal distribution

Comment: Can you explain the passages to compute it please? I know that the Brownian Motion follows a Gaussian distribution by definition, but I don't understand how I can arrive to the Moment Generating Function of the Gaussian Random Variable..

Comment: @dubidub [Here](http://www.le.ac.uk/users/dsgp1/COURSES/MATHSTAT/6normgf.pdf) is a link showing that