# Finite Dimensional Distributions of Stochastic Process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

If $X(t) = \int_0^t \! B(s)ds$ where $B(s)$ for $s > 0$ is a Brownian motion process.

Part a) what are the finite dimensional distributions of $X(t)$? (not an explicit formula, you don't need to evaluate integrals)

Part b) Compute the quadratic variation of $X(t)$.

Part c) is $X(t)$ a markov process?

My attempt:

Part a) I don't know how to do it without writing down the integral expression. 
Is it just Gaussian? will saying that be enough? I don't know what I am supposed to say for this part.

Part b) $X(t) = \int_0^t \! B(s)ds$. So $<X(t)> = \int_0^t \!1 <B(s)>ds = \int_0^t \! sds = 1/2t^2$ Is this correct ? (since quadratic variation of $B(s)$ is just $s$.

Part c) for this part is it enough to say $X(t)$ is a markov process because it is a function of another markov process ($B(s)$) and that function (integration) is invertible? I think I had seen this as a lemma somewhere.

I appreciate help/hints/suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, they are Gaussian. Have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243925/).
2. No, this is not correct; the identity $$\langle \int B_s \, ds \rangle = \int \langle B_s \rangle \, ds$$ does not hold. How did you *define* the quadratic variation? Hint: The process $X(t)$ is of bounded variation.
3. No, the process is not a Markov process, but one can show that the process $(X_t,B_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a Markov process. To see that $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is not a Markov process, calculate expressions of the form $$\mathbb{E}(f(X_t) \mid \mathcal{F}_s)$$ for $s \leq t$ and bounded, continuous functions $f$.

---

> **Lemma:** $\langle X \rangle_t = 0$.

**Proof:** Note that

$$|X_t-X_s| = \left| \int_s^t B_r \, dr \right| \leq |t-s| \sup_{r \in [s,t]} |B_r|$$

for any $0 \leq s \leq t$. Consequently,

$$\begin{align*} \sum_{i=0}^n |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}|^2 &\leq \sup_{i=0,\ldots,n} \sup_{r \in [t_i,t_{i+1}]} |B_r|^2 \cdot \sum_{i=0}^n |t_{i+1}-t_i|^2 \\ &\leq |T_n| \cdot \sup_{r \in [0,t]} |B_r|^2 \cdot \underbrace{\sum_{i=0}^n |t_{i+1}-t_i|}_{t}\end{align*}$$

for any partition $T_n$ of the interval $[0,t]$. Letting $|T_n| \to 0$, we find

$$\langle X \rangle_t = \lim_{|T_n| \to 0} \sum_{i=0}^n |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}|^2 = 0.$$

**Remark:** The proof actually shows  $$\langle X \rangle_t =0$$ for any process of the form $$X_t(\omega) = \int_0^t f(s,\omega) \, ds$$ where $f(\cdot,\omega)$ is a continous function for each fixed $\omega \in \Omega$.

Comment: I know that for y any deterministic function $s$, $X(t) = \int_0^t \! s dB(s)$ has quadratic variation $\int_0^t \! s^2ds$.Also for $N(t) = \int_0^t \! sdX(s)ds$ the qudratic we have $<N(t)> = \int_0^t \! s^2d<X(s)>$ so can I write $B(t)$ as X(t) = \iint\! dB(s)$

Comment: @Alex What do you mean by "deterministic function $s$"? $s$ is simply a variable of integration. And who claims that this second identity (the one with $\langle N \rangle$) holds?

Comment: I am sorry I am trying to edit my comment and it doesn't let me do that.

Comment: what I mean is if $f$ is any function of the variable of integration $s$.

Comment: In general, is there a computational shorthand for computing quadratic variation? it just seems difficult to use the definition directly.

Comment: I have the two identities in my notes, they are not from any book though so they might be wrong.

Comment: @Alex Well, perhaps you have something of the following form in your notes: If $f$ is a continuous function and $$X(t) := \int_0^t f(s) \, ds,$$ then $\langle X \rangle_t =0$. (Concerning computation: Not many, no. There are certain rules for martingales, but the given process is not a martingale.)

Comment: Well I just double checked and it just says $f$ and it is with respect to $dB(s)$ not $ds$. so $<\int_o^t f(x) dB(s)> = \int_o^t f(s)^2 ds$.

Comment: Then what is the asnwer for partb in this case?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, but that's something different; it's a stochastic integral. And the answer is $0$; see my previous comment.

Comment: Oh I see, do you mind me asking what general theorem this identity follows from?

Comment: @Alex Actually this follows more or less directly from the definition of quadratic variation. But so far, you haven't told me how the quadratic variation was defined in your class.

Comment: Here is how it is defined :$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} |X_{t_{i+1}} - X_{t_i}|^2 $. for $X_t$ being a stochastic process and $[T_n]$ for $n = 1, 2, ..$ is subdivision of $[0, t]$ with $|T_n|$ goes to zero.

Comment: @Alex see my edited answer.

Comment: I see, that makes sense, thanks alot!