# Integral of a Gaussian stochastic process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I investigate if the integral below make some sense. I think it makes, since I do not define de derivate of a stochastic process itself rather its integral over a time interval.

$
w(t) = \int_{0}^{t} z(t) \, dt,  \, z(t) = \mathcal{N}(\bar{z}, \Sigma)
$

Best regards

Comment: What is $z(t)$?

Comment: A gaussian process

Comment: Your question seems to be addressed here, in more detail: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471507/integral-of-a-gaussian-process