# 4th moment of stochastic integral?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Hi I want to evaluate the expectation of 4th moment of the stochastic integral
$$E \left[ \left( \int_0^T g(t)dW(t) \right)^4 \right]$$ and I found the following useful website [4th moment of a Wiener stochastic integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606138/4th-moment-of-a-wiener-stochastic-integral). But I'm confused the computation of expectation of it: how can we deduce like this,
$$
\mathbb{E}\left(X_t^4\right)=6 \int_0^t \int_0^s g(r)^2 g(s)^2 d r d s=3 \int_0^t \int_0^t g(r)^2 g(s)^2 d r d s.
$$
The reason why I ask a new question instead of setting a comment is that I don't have enough reputation.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [4th moment of a Wiener stochastic integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2606138/4th-moment-of-a-wiener-stochastic-integral)

Comment: Hello, I think no. I put the confused step of this answer in my question

Comment: I have numbered the equations in the question you linked. What *exactly* is the confusion?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm confused about the equation (5). I don't understand how we can change the upper limit of that integral $s$ to $t$ and the constant becomes $3$ from $6$.

Comment: Hint: in the step from $6...$ to $3...$ try in integration-by-parts. It could work wonders.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm confused about applying the integration-by-parts to double integral. And also if we apply it successfully, the upper limit$s$ will remain I think?

Comment: Hint: set $u(s)=\int_0^sg^2(r)\,dr$ and $v(s)=g^2(s)$. Now integrate by parts.

Comment: Since $u'(s)=v(s)$ you can also substitute to the new integration variable $u$. and realise that $\int_0^t\int_0^tg(r)^2g(s)^2\,dr\,ds$ is $u^2(t)$.

Comment: Many thanks for the useful hint and sorry for the delayed response. I think I have figured it now. By the way, for equation (4), the author said we need to use Itô's formula. Can we just use Itô isometry to deduce it?

Comment: Correct. I did  a bit of more cosmetics on that older post.