# Filtering of OU process - need validation of theoretical developments

Tags: stochastic-calculus, convolution

I derived the variance of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process filtered with a function A, but when I define A, I can't get an acceptable answer. I wonder whether my mistake is from the derivation before or after defining $A$. Hence, I would like to validate my derivation when A is not yet define. Here it is:

Given $\chi$ an OU process, I convolute $\chi$ with A (of integral 1)
\begin{align}
 {\chi} &= A \star \tilde{\chi} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t) \tilde{\chi}(p) \mathrm{d}p
\end{align}

The variance is (with $\mu_{\tilde{\chi}}=\mu_{\chi}$)
\begin{align}
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \mathbb{E}(\chi^2) - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left[\left( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t) \tilde{\chi}(p) \mathrm{d}p\right)^2\right] - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t) \tilde{\chi}(p) \mathrm{d}p \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t) \tilde{\chi}(s) \mathrm{d}s\right] - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t) \tilde{\chi}(p)   A(s-t) \tilde{\chi}(s) \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s\right] - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t) \mathbb{E}\left[ \tilde{\chi}(p) \tilde{\chi}(s) \right] \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \label{eqSI:var}
\end{align}

An OU process can be solved analytical following (with zero initial value)
\begin{align}
 \tilde{\chi}(t) = \mu_{\tilde{\chi}} (1-e^{-\frac{t}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \left(\frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} \right)^{{1}/{2}} \int_0^t e^{-\frac{t-s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_s
\end{align} 
The esperance $\mathbb{E}\left[ \tilde{\chi}(p) \tilde{\chi}(s) \right]$ is therefore
\begin{align}
 \mathbb{E}\left[ \tilde{\chi}(p) \tilde{\chi}(s) \right] &= \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( \mu_{\tilde{\chi}} (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \left(\frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} \right)^{{1}/{2}} \int_0^p e^{-\frac{p-u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \right) \right. \nonumber \\
 &\quad \left. \left( \mu_{\tilde{\chi}} (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \left(\frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} \right)^{{1}/{2}} \int_0^s e^{-\frac{s-u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \right) \right] \nonumber \\
          &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^p e^{-\frac{p-u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \int_0^s e^{-\frac{s-u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \right]  \nonumber \\
          &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathbb{E}\left[\int_0^{\min(p,s)} e^{\frac{u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \int_0^{\min(p,s)} e^{\frac{u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d} \mathcal{W}_u \right] \nonumber \\
          &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \frac{2 \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}} e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \int_0^{\min(p,s)} e^{2\frac{u}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d}u \nonumber \\
          &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{\min(p,s)}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right)
\end{align}
Injecting this in the variance, one gets
\begin{align}
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t) \mathbb{E}\left[ \tilde{\chi}(p) \tilde{\chi}(s) \right] \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
                 &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t) \left( \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 (1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) (1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) + \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{\min(p,s)}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \right) \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
                 &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)(1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}p  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t)(1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
                 &\quad + \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t)\sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{\min(p,s)}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s
\end{align}
Decomposing to remove the min function
\begin{align}
 & \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t)\sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{\min(p,s)}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \mathrm{d}p \mathrm{d}s \nonumber \\
 & \quad = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{s} A(p-t)  A(s-t)\sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \mathrm{d}p \right. \nonumber \\
 & \quad \left. + \int_{s}^{\infty} A(p-t)  A(s-t)\sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}  e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left( e^{2\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}s \nonumber \\
 & \quad = \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t) e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{s} A(p-t) \; 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \mathrm{d}p + \left( e^{2\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \int_{s}^{\infty} A(p-t) e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d}p \right]  \mathrm{d}s  \nonumber \\
 & \quad = \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( A(s-t) e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \int_{-\infty}^{s} A(p-t) \; 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}s\nonumber \\
 & \quad+ \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( A(s-t) 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \int_{s}^{\infty} A(p-t) e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}s 
\end{align}
Thus giving
\begin{align}
 \sigma_{\chi}^2 &= \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)(1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}p  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t)(1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
                 &\quad + \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t) e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{s} A(p-t) \; 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \mathrm{d}p + \left( e^{2\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} -1 \right) \int_{s}^{\infty} A(p-t) e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d}p \right]  \mathrm{d}s \nonumber \\
 & =\mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(p-t)(1-e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}p  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} A(s-t)(1-e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}}) \mathrm{d}s - \mu_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \nonumber \\
 &\quad + \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( A(s-t) e^{-\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \int_{-\infty}^{s} A(p-t) \; 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}s\nonumber \\
 & \quad+ \sigma_{\tilde{\chi}}^2 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( A(s-t) 2\mathrm{sinh}\left(\frac{s}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}\right) \int_{s}^{\infty} A(p-t) e^{-\frac{p}{T_{\tilde{\chi}}}} \mathrm{d}p \right) \mathrm{d}s 
\end{align}

Then one can continue the derivation by using the definition of $A$. Thanks for the help !

Comment: Please pardon me, but I am a bit confused about the way of filtrating here. An OU process $\chi_t$ is defined for $t\ge 0$. May I ask how to interpret $\int_{\mathbb{R}}A_{p-t}\chi_p{\rm d}p$ because here $p$ could be negative?

Comment: Sorry for the delay...that's a good point....I guess if in my derivation you replace $-\infty$ with $0$, it should remain correct right ? Or simply keep the same derivation but consider $\chi_p$ as 0 for $p<0$ and an OU process for $p>=0$.

Comment: I realize it should not be 0 but $T_A$ the timescale associated to the filter A (say a gaussian filter) so that at the beginning one doesn't filter the zeros...

Comment: Would you please provide a discrete example, say, by putting $A$ as a gaussian filter and write down its respective expression?

Comment: @hypernova hmm, trying to derive it I realized that my point about $T_A$ was not possible with a Gaussian filter which is never really zero...but using a triangular filter works and the issue is only for $t<T_A$ anyway.

Comment: That is, $(u+T_A)/T_A^2$ if $-T_A<u<0$ and $-(u-T_A)/T_A^2$ if $0<u<T_A$ and 0 elsewhere. Then considering $\chi_p=0$ if $p<0$ and using the filter for $u=p-t$, ones gets $\chi = \int_{-\infty}^{t-T_A} 0 dp + \int_{t-T_A}^{t+T_A} A(p-t)\tilde{\chi}_p dp + \int_{t+T_A}^{\infty} 0 dp$ . If $t<T_A$ then the second integral has indeed the range $[-T_A , 0]$ where $\chi_p=0$.

Comment: But since I am interested in the variance at $t\rightarrow \infty$, then I don't have any problem.