# Whether the integrated Brownian motion a Gaussian process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

We can define the integration of Brownian motion $W_t$ wrt t as
$$Z_t=\int_0^t W_sds.$$

We have know that $Z_t\sim N(0, t^3/3)$, but I am still not so sure 
that $Z_t$ is a Gaussian process or not. I don't have clue to follow
by definition of a Gaussian process.

Indeed, we can define the integral in Riemann sense:
for $0\le i\le n$, let $t_i=\frac {t} ni$, then
\begin{equation*}
Z_t=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac {t} nW_{\frac {t} ni}.
\end{equation*}
Since $W$ is a Gaussian process, the  linear combination $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac {t} nW_{\frac {t} ni}$
is also a Gaussian process. What about the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/243925/36150)

Comment: Thanks for your reminding.@saz