# Existence of Gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, wiener-measure, gaussian-measure

Let $\Omega=C([0,1],\mathbb{R})$, $(\Pi_t)_{t\in [0,1]}$ the canonical process with $\Pi_t(\omega)=\omega_t$, $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\Pi)$ and $\mathbb{F}$ the filtration generated by $\Pi$. Let $F:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous nondecreasing function.

I am currently reading a paper in which the following assertion is used without any reference.

There exists a unique probability measure $\mu$ on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ such that $\Pi$ is a centered Gaussian process on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{F},\mu)$ with $\mathrm{Cov}[\Pi_s,\Pi_t]=F(\min(s,t))$.

I can not find this claim anywhere. I would be very grateful for a reference to this assertion.

Comment: Hint . For $F(x)=x$ we know that the Gaussian process $\Pi_t$ is a Brownian motion . For general $F$ the Gaussian process $\int_0^t \Pi_s\,dF(s)$ has covariance function $F(\min(s,t))$. So the measure $\mu$ should be the image of the Wiener measure under the map $\Pi\mapsto \int_0^. \Pi_s\,dF(s)$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! But if I take $F(x)=x$ then $\int_0^t \Pi_s dF(s)$ has variance $s$ according to your hint. But here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/integral-of-brownian-motion-is-gaussian there is a different variance, namely $\int_0^t (s-t)^2 \, ds$, calculated. Do I miss something?

Comment: Good find. I made a mistake which got hopefully erased in the posted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $F(x)=x$ we know that the Gaussian process $\Pi_t$ is a Brownian motion. A general nondecreasing $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere on $[0,1]$. Then the process

$$
\int_0^t \sqrt{F'(s)}\,d\Pi_s=G(t)\Pi_t-G(0)\Pi_0-\int_0^t\Pi_s\,dG(s)\,,\quad\text{ where }G(s):=\sqrt{F'(s)}
$$
has variance $\int_0^t F'(s)\,ds=F(t)$ and covariance function $F(\min(s,t))$.

The measure $\mu$ you are looking for is then the image (push forward) of the Wiener  measure under the map
$$
\Pi_{\,\textstyle.}\mapsto G\,\Pi_{\,\textstyle.}-G(0)\Pi_0-\int_0^{\,\textstyle\cdot}\Pi_s\,dG(s)
$$
from $C([0,1],\mathbb R)$ to itself.

Comment: Hmm, why does $\int_0^t \sqrt{F'(s)}\,d\Pi_s=\int_0^t\Pi_s\,dG(s)$ hold? We have a continuous local martingale on the left hand side and an adapted continuous process of locally bounded variation on the right hand side. If they were equal, they must both be 0, right?

Comment: Correct ! Fixed one more mistake .

Comment: Great, thank you!