# Distribution of $\int_0^t s^2 B(s) \, ds$ where $B$ is a standard Brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I guess $\int_0^t s^2 B(s) \, ds$ is a normal distribution as $\int_0^t B(s) \, ds$ but I don't know how to argue that.

Comment: $X=\int_{0}^{t} s^2 B(s) \, \mathrm{d}s$ is a "linear combination" of jointly normal variables, hence is again normal. In fact, since each $B(s)$ is centered, $X$ is also centered. So you only need to figure out the variance of $X$ in order to completely specify the distribution of $X$.

Comment: @SangchulLee I understand a linear combination of jointly normal variables is again normal. But an integration is defined as a limitation. Why this limitation of these normal random variables is still normal?

Comment: It is a well-known fact that the limit in distribution of normal distributions is again normal. I believe the proof can be found in many textbooks, or even in this community (for instance, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/232540/9340)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

From
$$
\frac{t^3}{3}B_t=\int_0^ts^2\,B_s\,ds+\int_0^t\frac{s^3}{3}\,dB_s
$$
it follows that
$$
\int_0^ts^2\,B_s\,ds=\int_0^t\frac{t^3-s^3}{3}\,dB_s
$$
which is Gaussian with mean zero and variance
$$
\int_0^t\frac{(t^3-s^3)^2}{9}\,ds\,.
$$
Can you proceed?