# Mean and Variance Convergence with r.v.

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, random-variables, weak-convergence

Let $(X_n)_{n\ge 1}$ be a sequence of random variables, with respective distributions being Gaussian, with respective mean $\mu_n \in \mathbb R$ and variance 
$\sigma_n^2 > 0$. Prove that if $X_n$ converges in distribution, then $\mu_n$ and 
$\sigma^2_n$ need to converge, and identify
the limiting random variable. fb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hints** Since $(X_n)_n$ is convergent in distribution (to some random variable $X$), the family of distributions $\{\mathbb{P}_{X_n}; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is [tight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_of_measures). From this one can conclude that the sequences $(\mu_n)_n$ and $(\sigma_n^2)_n$ are bounded (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/116613/tightness-condition-in-the-case-of-normally-distributed-random-variables/116651#116651)). Thus, there exist convergent subsequences, i.e. $$\mu := \lim_{k \to \infty} \mu_{n_k} \qquad \qquad \sigma^2 := \lim_{k \to \infty} \sigma_{n_k}^2 \tag{1}$$ 
Moreover, the weak convergence of $(X_n)_n$ implies the convergence of the characteristic functions, $$\mathbb{E}\exp \left( \imath \, \xi \cdot X_n \right) \to \mathbb{E}\exp \left( \imath \, \xi \cdot X \right) \qquad (n \to \infty)$$
Using the explicit formula for characteristic functions of Gaussian random variables and $(1)$, we conclude $X \sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.