# Integral of a Brownian bridge with respect to time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

Let $(W_s)_{s\geq 0}$ be a Brownian motion and $t$ a fixed point in time. What is the distribution of $$\Big.\int_0^tW_sds\Big|W_t$$
i.e. the integral of a Brownian bridge with respect to time? Is it Gaussian?

Answer (score 1):

For convenience, I will take $t=1$. The same kind of calculations apply for general $t$. As, $W_s\vert W_1$ is Gaussian process, the lebesgue integral is  Gaussian RV : Approximate the given integral as Riemann sums and each Riemann sum is Gaussian and hence the limit will be Gaussian. Look here for similar problem : [click here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333455/mean-and-variance-convergence-with-r-v)

The expectation of it is given by $\int_0^1tW_1dt=0.5W_1$

Comment: Actually the expectation is $\frac12tW_t$, thus, $\frac12W_1$ assuming that $t=1$.

Comment: @Did : Edited the answer. Thanks!

Comment: yeah but what is its variance? can't find it anywhere